# The navigation animation of my Back button doesn't look like as a return flipping

Tags: xcode4.2

In story board, i use the navigation controller, two views, button1 to go to view2 and button2 to go back to view1, i use the Push segue directly in story board when configuring the two view.
Now, when i go from view1 to view2, the animation movement is from right to left, so it's ok.
But when going back, the animation (in my opinion) need to be from left to right, which isn't the case, so it's also from right to left.
How can i make it moving from left to right showing that it would really be a returning movement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like your back button calls pushViewController: instead of popViewController: ?